# Singletons in Restlet applications for working with variables

Tags: java, restlet

I need your help. I've a Java Restlet server for indexing documents. I would like to have Map (synchronized) where each resource can write to or read from. As I found each resource is different thread. Main problem is, that in ServerRunner I put class as a parameter not object, so I don't know how to give there information with this Map. I was trying to use singletons like this:

**ServerRunner**

```
public class ServerRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8888, ChickenResource.class);
    //server.start();

    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8888);

    DocIndexingResource test = DocIndexingResource.getInstance();
    List<IndexedFile> listIndexedFiles = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IndexedFile>());
    test.setupMap(listIndexedFiles);
    component.getDefaultHost().attach("/chickens/{id}", test.getClass());


    //listIndexedFiles.add(new IndexedFile("asas", "aa", 2, null));



    //DocIndexingResource.getInstance().addIndexedFile();

    System.out.println("salajlalasjaksadsa");
    component.start();
}
}
```

and here is DocIndexingResource class:

```
package docindexing.docindexing;

import java.rmi.server.UID;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class DocIndexingResource extends ServerResource {


private List<IndexedFile> listIndexedFiles;

@Override
protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
    super.doInit();
}

public static DocIndexingResource getInstance (){
    return instance;
}

private static DocIndexingResource instance = new DocIndexingResource();


/*@Get("json")
public Chicken getChicken() {
    return new Chicken(1000, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}*/

@Get("json")
public String findById() {
    int id = Integer.parseInt((String)getRequestAttributes().get("id"));
    //return new Chicken(100+id,0);
    return "{\"width\": "+id+"}";
}

@Post
public String addIndexedFile(IndexedFile indexedFile) {
    System.out.println(indexedFile.getFileName() + " --- "+indexedFile.getFileContent());
    //synchronized (listIndexedFiles) {
        listIndexedFiles.add(indexedFile);
    //}

    indexedFile.listIndexedFiles.add(indexedFile);
    System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    System.out.println(listIndexedFiles.size()+ " ---- " + indexedFile.listIndexedFiles.size());
    return new UID().toString();
}

/*public String getChicken() {
    return "{ \"name\" : \"Kurczak\" }";
}*/

void setupMap(List<IndexedFile> listIndexedFiles) {
    this.listIndexedFiles = listIndexedFiles;
}
}
```

I was thinking that this should work, but unfortunately it gives me an exception on listIndexedFiles.add(indexedFile);

```
Jan 27, 2014 12:42:33 PM org.restlet.resource.UniformResource doCatch
WARNING: Exception or error caught in resource
java.lang.NullPointerException
at docindexing.docindexing.DocIndexingResource.addIndexedFile(DocIndexingResource.java:47)
```

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You have two list `listIndexedFiles` in both classes `DocIndexingResource ` and `IndexedFile ` ?

Comment: Yes, It was only because of testing... Now I removed it from indexedFile but without success... Simply what I need is to create somewhere a synchronized HashMap (in the code it's arraylist only because of testing) and from each resource communicate with this hashmap

Comment: I had not found any problem in your code you have posted. but may be this line `indexedFile.listIndexedFiles.add(indexedFile);` create problem because `listIndexedFiles` is null for `indexedFile` object.

Answer (score 0):

RESTlet ServerResources are not singletons.  You pass the class of the ServerResource to the Application/component and it creates them as it needs them.  You are doing this here:

```
component.getDefaultHost().attach("/chickens/{id}", test.getClass());
```

There are multiple problems here. It's probably not ideal but you could make the `listIndexedFiles` a static member (and initialise it) to achieve what you want.

Comment: make static listIndexedFile in ServerRunner? how to do that? I was trying it, but it's not running

Comment: `private static List<IndexedFile> listIndexedFiles;` - you need to stop trying to use the ServerResource as a singleton.